# Create ImageBox in Microsoft Word document and insert image with Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, image-processing, ms-word, insert-image

I'm working on a project in VB which has to do with document processing in Microsoft Word. I have difficulty on creating an ImageBox with certain size in a the document. Does anybody have an idea on how to do this? Can it even be done? The goal is to create the ImageBox and then insert an image to this box. The image must stretch and get the size of the ImageBox.

What I've done until now is this:

```
(...)  
Dim NewSize As Size
NewSize = New Size(Width, Height)
ResizedImage = New Bitmap(ImageToInsert, NewSize)
(...)
WordDocument.AddPicture(DirectoryAddress & "\ResizedImage." & ImageExtension)
```

Though, what this code does, is to insert an image with specified size in the Word document. What I want is, the image to stretch and get the size of the ImageBox that will have been created. I hope I was clear enough.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Natively, Word does not support .NET controls on its document surface. If a VSTO Add-in is used, then it's possible. VSTO "wraps" WinForms controls in "ActiveX", which the document surface supports... But doing so is non-trivial (there was a discussion once, many years ago, in the MSDN VSTO forum where a MS Dev went through the steps). Other than that, the closest you can get would be a Word table *cell*, which will automatically limit an image in *one* dimension (maintaining aspect ratio in the other dimension).

Comment: The simplest way is to use a document that has a one-cell table (borderless or otherwise) of fixed height and width wherever you want the image to appear. The table can be in-line or wrapped, whichever you prefer. Any image inserted into such a table will be constrained to fit the space available, at the correct aspect ratio. Alternatively, you can insert the image as an inlineshape or shape and apply the scaling via code.

Comment: Thank you @CindyMeister for your response, but this method won't work... Unfortunately the cell size will get the size of the image instead of happening the opposite. This doesn't happen only through VB code but through the official Word App as well. If you paste an image into a cell and the image is bigger than the cell, then the cell's size will increase to image size... Any ideas? Did I misunderstand  something?

Comment: Thank you @macropod for your response, but this method won't work... Unfortunately the cell size will get the size of the image instead of happening the opposite. This doesn't happen only through VB code but through the official Word App as well. If you paste an image into a cell and the image is bigger than the cell, then the cell's size will increase to image size... Any ideas? Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: It's necessary to set *one* dimension of the cell (width or height) to an *exact* measurement. By default, the cell will resize unless a dimension is set to an exact size.

Comment: «Unfortunately the cell size will get the size of the image instead of happening the opposite». Not so! If the cell is changing size, that's only because you haven't fixed the dimensions as I plainly said is required. The method is well known, tried and proven.

Comment: @CindyMeister I must be doing something wrong.. That's what I've done until now... It won't work..                                                                                        Dim NewTable As Word.Table
NewTable = WordDoc.Tables.Add(para.Range, 1, 1)
NewTable.Cell(1,1).SetWidth(500,1)
NewTable.Cell(1,1).SetHeight(389,1)
InsertImageFunction(lineReadX,WordDoc)
Dim objDoc = WordDoc                                                                                                                    Dim objShapes = NewTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.InlineShapes
objShapes.AddPicture(Image.jpg")

Comment: @macropod That's what I've done until now... It won't work.. Sorry for the code formating. I don't know how to write code in the comments' section..                    Dim NewTable As Word.Table____NewTable = WordDoc.Tables.Add(para.Range, 1, 1)_____NewTable.Cell(1,1).SetWidth(500,1)___
NewTable.Cell(1,1).SetHeight(389,1)____
Dim objDoc = WordDoc_____Dim objShapes = NewTable.Cell(1,1).Range.InlineShapes______objShapes.AddPicture(Image.jpg")

Comment: @macropod Thanks for the answer. I still have some issues though.. I posted them under your code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @CindyMeister and @macropod I managed to create what I needed. So here is the answer:

```
Dim rng As Word.Range
(...)
rng = para.Range
(...)

Dim img As Image = Image.FromFile(imagePath)
Dim objtable as Word.Table

'In my case I needed a temporary paragraph to be added for my project and later delete it. If you don't need it, just don't declare it.

Dim tempTablePara As Word.Paragraph = WordDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add() 'Previously declared WordDoc as Word.Document
objtable = WordDoc.Tables.Add(rng, 1, 1)
objtable.Cell(1, 1).Width = img.Width * 0.75 'width is in pixels, convert to points
objtable.Cell(1, 1).Height = img.Height* 0.75 'height is in pixels, convert to points
objtable.Cell(1, 1).HeightRule = Word.WdRowHeightRule.wdRowHeightExactly ' Done so as the cell to get the same size with the picture

Dim objShapes = objtable.Range.InlineShapes

rng = tempTablePara.Range
tempTablePara.Range.Delete()

objShapes.AddPicture(imagePath)

'add cell borders

With objtable.Rows(1).Cells.Borders
.InsideLineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle
.OutsideLineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle
End With
```

Extra. What I was looking for, was to insert an image to an already designed frame in a word document. So for me the pre-designed frame was a one cell table. If you just want to add a frame around a picture then the following code should work just fine.

```
Dim shape
(...)

shape = WordDoc.InlineShapes.AddPicture(imagePath, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, rng)
rng = shape.Range
Dim objshape As Word.InlineShape
objshape = shape
objshape.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingleWavy
objshape.Borders.OutsideColor = Word.WdColor.wdColorBlack
rng.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you were to look at the properties of the table you're creating, you would see that you have *not* created a table with a fixed height and width. To do that, you could use something like:

```
NewTable = WordDoc.Tables.Add(para.Range, 1, 1, 0, 0)
NewTable.Cell(1,1).Width(500)
NewTable.Cell(1,1).Height(389)
NewTable.Cell(1, 1).HeightRule(2)
```

or, in VBA:

```
Set NewTable = WordDoc.Tables.Add(para.Range, 1, 1, 0, 0)
NewTable.Cell(1,1).Width = 500
NewTable.Cell(1,1).Height = 389
NewTable.Cell(1, 1).HeightRule = 2
```

Comment: First of all many thanks! But still I have two issues. The first one is, that the picture must appear in a box. In this (current) solution you have posted, Word, doesn't show the cell's margins.. Is there any solution to that? My second issue is that, when I use the first block of the code you posted, I get an error from the compiler saying: "Too many arguments to Property Width as Single" Do you know why this happens?  For this reason I used the second block of code that does the job, but as I said I can't see the margins of the cell...

Comment: Well, study the Word object model and add the borders... It's not rocket science! I have no idea why you'd get the error message for the width and not for the height using vb.net - I don't use it.

Comment: The same happens in Height as well. I just mentioned Width as an example